# How to iterate through files in a directory and plug the INFO into a MySQL database with PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql

Ok, I have a folder on my desktop with a bunch of files in it. I want to iterate through it, parse out the INTEGERs (years) from the title, open and parse out the information in each file and put it into a MySQL database.

The files are .txt files that look like this:

```
yob1880.txt
yob1881.txt
yob1882.txt ...and so on
```

The information in the files look like this:

```
Mary,F,7065
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
Elizabeth,F,1939     ... and so on
```

I want to parse the information into a MySQL database. I can't seem to get the parsed INTEGERs (years) into the database as the table's name. So, I think I need to put all the years into the database as its own AUTO-INCREMENTED ID then link to it. But, how would I link the info to the corresponding year.

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import glob

conn = sqlite3.connect('babynames.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Babynames;

CREATE TABLE Babynames (
    names   TEXT UNIQUE,
    gender TEXT,
    ranking INTEGER
    )''')

folder = "folder/location"
files = glob.glob(folder) # file names with content attached

for f in files:
    cut = f.split('/')[-1]
    cut2 = cut.split('.')[0]
    yob = cut2[3:] #parses out years from title
    for i in files:
        with open(i) as f:
            content = f.read()
            line = content.split(',')
            names = line[0]
            gender = line[1]
            ranking = line[2] # need to get only integers

            cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Babynames (names, 
            gender, ranking)
                VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )''', ( names, gender, ranking ) )

conn.commit()
```

This code only gives one table with three columns and ten rows when there should be thousands of rows. :/

It doesn't seem to iterate through ALL the files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what exactly you are trying to do with your code. Here are piece of code to iterate through each file and read each file content and then split each line by `,` and get the third element of each line.

```
folder = "folder/location/"
files = glob.glob(folder + '*.txt')  // get all list of files
for file in files : // iterate through files
    with open(file, 'r') as myfile: // read each file
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '') // store file content
        for d in data:
            yob = d.split(',')[2]
            print yob
```

**Note :** I haven't tested this code. So, let me know, if you encountered any error.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

for file in files:
  data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
  cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Babynames (names, 
            gender, ranking)
                VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )''', ( data[0].values, data[1].values, data[2].values ) )
```